# Returning Character Array via Assignment Operator

Tags: c++, arrays, return-value, assignment-operator, character-arrays

So this is a homework assignment, there might be come constraints that are ridiculous but please bear with me. This is just a simple function but drawn out. I need to return a character array via assignment operator but it doesn't seem to be working at all. I've tried pointers, but no luck.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char* findMax(char*, char*);

int main()
{
    char aArray[50] = "Hello World",
        bArray[50] = "dlroW olleH",
        maxArray[50];

    maxArray[50] = findMax(aArray, bArray);

    cout << maxArray << " is the bigger of the 2 strings" << endl;
    return 0;
}

char* findMax(char* strA, char* strB){
    char* maxStr;

    if(strcmp(strA, strB) < 1)
        maxStr = strB;
    else
        maxStr = strA;

    return maxStr;
}
```

if I cout the return value of `findMax()` it does print out the value of bArray, but geting it into maxArray via assignment operator isn't working at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. As written, `maxArray` is an array of characters. Arrays can't be directly assigned to. Instead you need to copy each character one by one. You could do that with a loop, or by calling the `strcpy` standard library function.

```
char maxArray[50];

strcpy(findMax(aArray, bArray), maxArray);
```

The other way is to change the declaration of `maxArray` to be a `char *`, a pointer. Pointers can be assigned to directly without having to loop or invoke a function.

```
char *maxArray;

maxArray = findMax(aArray, bArray);
```

The difference between this and the first solution is subtle, but important. With `char maxArray[50]` you are actually allocating a third array of 50 characters, separate from `aArray` and `bArray`. This array has its own storage, its own 50 bytes of memory.

In the second you don't create a third array. You merely create a pointer which can point to other arrays already in existence. After the assignment, `maxArray` becomes an indirect reference to either `aArray` or `bArray`. It's not a *copy* of one of those arrays, it *points to* one of them.

Comment: Ah, the maxArray pointer was what I was looking for. Thank you!